# Why do I fail to get a video when I use save animation in Python?

Tags: python, animation

I would like to save an animation of vectors created using Python. When I execute the program, I get several images _tmp0001.png until _tmp0100.png but momentarily. When the execution ends, the 100 images disappear and no avi file is produced. Please here is a minimal working environment:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from numpy import pi

X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.2),np.arange(0,2*np.pi,.2) )  
U = np.cos(X)
V = np.sin(Y)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
Q = ax.quiver( X, Y, U, V, pivot='mid', color='r', units='inches')

ax.set_xlim(0, 2*pi)
ax.set_ylim(0, 2*pi)

def update_quiver(num, Q, X, Y):
    U = np.cos(X + num*0.1)
    V = np.sin(Y + num*0.1)
    Q.set_UVC(U,V)
    return Q,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, fargs=(Q, X, Y),
    interval=10, blit=False)
anim.save("movie.avi", codec='avi')

plt.show()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code generated an avi file after small modification and installation of `ffmpeg`.

- I removed `codecs='avi'` argument:

  ```
  anim.save("movie.avi")
  ```
- Removed call to `plt.show`:

  ```
  #plt.show()
  ```

Here's the generated video: http://youtu.be/p4kpA9mcqbs

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but no avi was generated! I have already installer ffmpeg (using the steps found in the internet!) I can't find any video!! No error message was got. Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose that you find the video in the same directory!

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik, Is the directory that contains `ffmpeg` in the PATH?

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik, Yes, the `movie.avi` file was generated where I exectued the script.

Comment: Yes! Here what I found in path c:\ffmpeg\bin; I don't know if I succeeded in the installation of FFmpeg or not

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik, Add the directory to the PATH: `SET PATH=%PATH%:c:\ffmpeg\bin`, then try again.

Comment: I wrote that in the invite of commands but no results! I have tried also to put: `anim.save("movie.avi", codec='ffmpeg')` but always no video was created! I am amazed how it can't work although no error message is obtained!!!

Comment: I tried also other video types such as flv and mp4 but no results! The installation of FFmpeg was successful since FFMPEJ -version returns no error messages. During the execution, temporary images were created in the directory _tmpXXXX and then disappear without giving birth to any video. Just a last chance FalseTrue! do you have any idea to get rid of this shameful situation? best

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik, I have no idea. FYI, here's the terminal record that what I did: http://asciinema.org/a/8368

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot! I think it was a pity to work with windows! I will familiarize myself more with ubuntu to do things right! Danke